# Calculate percentile for every value in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, scipy, percentile

I am trying to calculate percentile for every value in column `a` from a DataFrame `x`.

Is there a better way to write the following piece of code?

```
x["pcta"] = [stats.percentileofscore(x["a"].values, i) 
                                    for i in x["a"].values]
```

I would like to see better performance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems like you want [`Series.rank()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
x.loc[:, 'pcta'] = x.rank(pct=True) # will be in decimal form
```

Performance:

```
import scipy.stats as scs

%timeit [scs.percentileofscore(x["a"].values, i) for i in x["a"].values]
1000 loops, best of 3: 877 µs per loop

%timeit x.rank(pct=True)
10000 loops, best of 3: 107 µs per loop
```

Comment: The percentileofscore method lets you find out the percentiles of a column based on another. Is there any way that rank allows you to do that? I have created a subset of the column and want to calculate the rank values for values in that subset based on the main column.