# Dataframe Percentile calculation from 0 to 100

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentile

I need to calculate the percentile of the value in a dataframe. The closest way to calculate percentile as what other have suggested is to use pandas.DataFrame.rank(pct=True) ([Calculate percentile for every value in a column of dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211653/calculate-percentile-for-every-value-in-a-column-of-dataframe)) . However, the method will not give me starting from 0th percentile:

```
num = pd.DataFrame([3,5,6,8])
num.rank(pct=True)
      0
0  0.25
1  0.50
2  0.75
3  1.00
```

Is there a better method to obtain something like this, from 0th percentile to 100th percentile:

```
      0
0  0.00
1  0.33
2  0.66
3  1.00
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define percentile?

Comment: I would assume the order of ranking below its own value. Assume three number; it would be 100th percentile, 50th percentile and 0th percentile (0th because no other number is lower than that value)

Comment: It is something similar to what Tableau has defined: 
"All other values are assigned a percentile based on their ranking. So for a set of four values, 1, 3, 22, 67, the percentiles would be 0%, 33%, 67%, and 100%, respectively."

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_definebasic_percentile.html

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to have lowest ranked value assigned to the 0 percentile and the highest ranked value assigned to the 100 percentile, and all other values assigned a percentile based on their ranking. 
The following code achieves that:

```
ranks = num.rank()
(ranks - ranks.min())/(ranks.max() - ranks.min())
```